# Set of all orthogonal matrices over $\mathbb C$ is compact/not

Tags: matrices, compactness

How to show the fact that the set of all orthogonal matrices over $\mathbb C$ is compact

By an orthogonal matrix over $\mathbb C$ I mean a matrix $A$ satisfying $AA^T=I$ and here $A^T=(a_{ji})$ where $A=(a_{ij})$

It is not the same as unitary matrix where in unitary matrix we take transpose and then conjugate or vice versa

I know that set of all orthogonal matrices over $\mathbb R$ is compact.

I think the closedness of the set will follow from the same arguements as in the above case. But the boundedness part not sure

Comment: Do you mean unitary? Because an orthogonal matrix is real by definition.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate? This question is for 2x2 matrices... But one of the answers addreses the n-dimensional case.... http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137354/compactness-of-the-set-of-all-unitary-matrices-in-m-2-mathbbc?rq=1

Comment: Who says that @JohnColanduoni

Comment: @learnmore Every definition I've ever seen, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) for example.

Comment: unitary and orthogonal over $\mathbb C$ are not same !so how is this a duplicate

Comment: I have edited it @WillieWong

Comment: The word "orthogonal" *is* sometimes used for complex matrices st. $AA^T = I$, cf. for example [Orthogonal group (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Over_the_complex_number_field). More generally you can talk about the orthogonal group of any quadratic form (and since there's only one quadratic form on $\mathbb{C}^n$ anyway...)

Comment: @Najib: and, of course, the noncompactness of the orthogonal matrices over complex is intimately tied to the fact that for $n > 1$ the set of numbers $$\{ (z_1, \ldots, z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n | (z_1)^2 + (z_2)^2 + \ldots + (z_n)^2 = 1\}$$ is noncompact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not bounded, unless you are working with $1\times 1$ matrices.

The only complex, $1\times 1$ orthogonal matrix are $(1)$ and $(-1)$.

In $2\times 2$ (and by extension you get $n\times n$) you can consider the family, where $\lambda \geq 1$ is a real parameter,
$$ A_\lambda = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & i \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 1} \\
- i \sqrt{\lambda^2 - 1} & \lambda \end{pmatrix} $$
which you can easily check to be orthogonal. But any matrix norm of $A_\lambda$ would tell you it is of size $\approx \lambda$.

Comment: So except the 1 X 1 case, the subgroup is not compact, right?

Comment: ... yes (for the usual topologies you may want to consider).